# Using HttpClient in Xamarin PCL to post

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

I'm trying to make a post to a rest api using HttpClient PCL in Xamarin. I have the following code but I'm getting a 404. Note that I don't have the real ip address here but when I use Hurl.It with the real one it connects just fine, but here just a 404. What am I missing?

```
string url = "http://myaddresshere/services/rest/auth/login";
string result = String.Empty;

using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>(txtUsername.Text, "username"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>(txtPassword.Text, "password")
    });

    using (var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content)) {
        using (var responseContent = response.Content) {
            result = await responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have port forwarding on your router? Do you have a firewall (in router or PC) blocking you?

Comment: Calling the API from a normal visual studio project works so I wouldn't think this would be the issue then? Is the above code supposed to work? Like does it work for you in a Xamarin PCL project?

Comment: Are you saying that from a non-PCL project (>= .NET 4.5), the *exact* code above works fine but it does not from a PCL? A quick way to be certain would be to create a console app that references a PCL containing the above code *and* paste the same code directly in the console app, and have the app call both. That will take Xamarin out of the equation and should help isolate whether the problem is truly with the PCL version of HttpClient.

Comment: Believe it or not it's because my key/value is reversed. Ido pointed this out and when I changed it it work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably switch in your code:

```
new KeyValuePair<string, string>(txtUsername.Text, "username"),
 new KeyValuePair<string, string>(txtPassword.Text, "password")
```

To:

```
 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", txtUsername.Text),
 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", txtPassword.Text)
```

Comment: I don't have the login method in the api. I didn't make the api and I don't have access to it. As stated though everything works fine when I try this with Hurl.It website. This didn't work either :(. Can't believe it's this difficult to make a web service call in a PCL. My PCL Xamarin experience so far is not good :(

Comment: This is an iOS app that I'm working on a mac. Fiddler doesn't seem to exist for mac that I can see.

Comment: BTW, I'm using Xamarin for more than a month, and I have built both the server in web api and the consumed services in xamarin forms, and I didn't have a problem with that area, I guess that there is a small configuration that it currently blocking you, we'll just need to see what it is. however, in XForms there are some difficulties when you dive into deeper actions, as there are some still many unimplemented features.

Comment: So I start a Charles session and select Sequence and if I navigate using the normal chrome web browser on my mac I entries start to show up which is good and normal, just testing that. I then start a new session and when I step through my code ZERO lines show up in Charles. It's like it's doing nothing at all. This is from the iPhone 5s iOS 8.2 simulator. Something seems like it's not even letting it try. Even from my phone I see no activity in Charles on the PostAsync() line. It's not trying for some reason.

Comment: Let's try another case, Let's assume that this class that calls the login api is called 'LoginService' and has a 'login' method. in your UI form class, I assume you're calling to something like this : var result = await LoginService.Login(userName, password), right? can you try to replace the await with 'ContinueWith' statement to something like this: LoginService.Login(userName, password).ContinueWith(response =>
            {
                 var result  = response.Result;
            });

Comment: The code you see above is all done inside the login button click handler.

async void btnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e){}

Comment: Can you try to refactor it, move it to a different function, and then invoke this method with continueWith? the new method should be async, but the loginClicked should not be async

Comment: What should I be returning from my new function (named it Login())?

Comment: I guess that it should be a  Task<User> Where the User is the response from the method after you parsed the response from the api and deserialized it.

Comment: As I fumble around with this refactor what is your thought process with this idea? Are you trying to rule something out? Just curious to know.

Comment: I had a similar problem when I started writing Xamarin, and for some reason, don't ask me why, await with async never triggered an API call to the webserver, only continueWith.

Comment: Do you have an example of how this would work with my above code? I never used ContinueWith() and can't seem to get this refactor to compile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73669/discussion-between-ido-tene-and-user441521).

Comment: Switching the key/value worked! Thank you so much. Would have never guessed this was causing a 404.

Comment: Almost any key-value pair in any language and on any platform is represented as key first, value second. Unless someone has assembled a screwy API. Nice easy fix!